# How to initialize a boolean array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

I am learning javascript and I want to initialize a boolean array in javascript.

I tried doing this:

```
 var anyBoxesChecked = [];
 var numeroPerguntas = 5;     
 for(int i=0;i<numeroPerguntas;i++)
 {
    anyBoxesChecked.push(false);
 }
```

But it doesn't work.

After googling I only found [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/330151/initialize-boolean-array-as-all-true-unity-js.html) way:

```
 public var terroristShooting : boolean[] = BooleanArrayTrue(10);
 function BooleanArrayTrue (size : int) : boolean[] {
     var boolArray = new boolean[size];
     for (var b in boolArray) b = true;
     return boolArray;
 }
```

But I find this a very difficult way just to initialize an array. Any one knows another way to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were getting an error with that code that debugging would have caught. `int` isn't a JS keyword. Use `var` and your code works perfectly.

```
var anyBoxesChecked = [];
var numeroPerguntas = 5;     
for (var i = 0; i < numeroPerguntas; i++) {
  anyBoxesChecked.push(false);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h8ec2p70/)

Comment: Don't forget to tip the waitress on your way out :)

Comment: @AlbertoCrespo, by the way that second code example you gave was UnityScript rather than JavaScript. They're similar in some ways but that code would never have worked outside of a Unity environment.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know the existence of that!

Comment: amazing answer very useful

Answer (score 98):

I know it's late but i found this efficient method to initialize array with Boolean values

```js
    var numeroPerguntas = 5;     
    var anyBoxesChecked = new Array(numeroPerguntas).fill(false);
    console.log(anyBoxesChecked);
```

Comment: Great answer. To read more about the method refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: Just a side note, this method is not supported on IE

Comment: Is that 1D or 2D?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
`Array.from({length: 5}, i => i = false);`

Comment: I think this could be improved by using the map function (second argument) correctly. To expand, using `i` there implies the first argument is the index, when it's in fact the element at that index (see docs you linked). Also, assigning to `i` isn't what's making this work; it's the fact that `i = rvalue` returns `rvalue`, which is all you have to do for this to work. Hence, `Array.from({length: 5}, _ => false);` IMO would be a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

it can also be one solution

```js
var boolArray = [true,false];
console.log(boolArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Array.apply and map...

```js
var numeroPerguntas = 5;  
var a = Array.apply(null, new Array(numeroPerguntas)).map(function(){return false});
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more efficient to use an integer and bitwise operations?

```
<script>
var boolarray = 0;

function comparray(indexArr) {
  if (boolarray&(2**(indexArr))) {
    boolarray -= 2**(indexArr);
    //do stuff if true
  } else {
    boolarray += 2**(indexArr);
    //do stuff if false
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    Array.from({length: 5}, () => false)
```

Sample:

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 5}, () => false)
console.log(arr.join(", "))
```